# SqlAlchemy "after_insert" event not triggered on bulk insert operation

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

So there is a list of data that I am inserting onto postgres at once with:

```
session.bulk_insert_mappings(model_name, data)
session.commit()
```

However when this operation is performed the event "**after_insert**" is not triggered.Do the events in Sqlalchemy not trigger for bulk operation or am I missing something? I am new to the event handling in Sqlalchemy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bulk proccessing in the ORM does not support events - see [ORM Compatibility / Caveats](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/persistence_techniques.html#orm-compatibility-caveats)

> The bulk insert / update methods lose a significant amount of functionality versus traditional ORM use. The following is a listing of features that are not available when using these methods:
>
> ...
>
> - ORM events such as MapperEvents.before_insert(), etc. The bulk session methods have no event support.